# Error: "No implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer"

Tags: ruby, arrays, data-structures, hash

I'm trying to store the team names in either `@wins` or `@loss` depending on the home and away scores associated with the respective key.

```
@leaderboard_info = [{
                      home_team:"Patriots",
                      away_team: "Broncos",
                      home_score: 7,
                      away_score: 3
                      }, 
                      #more info in hashes.........]

@wins = []
@loss = []

@leaderboard_info.each do |game|
  game.each do |key,value|
    if value[:home_score] > value[:away_score]  #7 > 3
      @win << value[:home_team]   #Patriots
      @loss << value[:away_team]  #Broncos 
    else
      @loss << value[:home_team]
      @win << value[:away_team]
    end
  end
end
```

But I keep running into this error

```
[]': no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer (TypeError)
```

The `if` statement should be grabbing the specific values of 7 and 3. Afterwards it should be pushing the team names stored by the value. Why isn't it working? I tried it with `key[home_score]` etc. but it still doesn't work.

Comment: That is a *lot* of instance variables, especially given your comment `#more info in hashes`. Do you realise that all of that information is duplicated for every object you create?

Comment: Also, you have defined the array `@wins = []` but you are pushing information onto `@win`. It is impossible to tell what the correct code should be without seeing the rest of your program, but from what you have shown it looks very hastily assembled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should remove your double loop and change it to looks like:

```
@leaderboard_info.each do |game|
  if game[:home_score] > game[:away_score]
    @win << game[:home_team]
    @loss << game[:away_team]
  else
     @loss << game[:home_team]
     @win << game[:away_team]
  end
end
```

Comment: Aguardientico, thanks so much, I finally got it to work. I really appreciate it.

Comment: glad to be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you're calling each on a Hash, which yields (as your code points out) a key and value for *each record* in the Hash.  So when you call value[:home_team], you're using the [] method on a String ("Patriots").  The [] method on String expects a Fixnum (for breaking up a String).